# JBDC and Phpmyadmin / MySQL not connecting

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, phpmyadmin

Could someone explain to me where I'm going wrong with the following code:

```
package newdbtet;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class NewDBTet {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InstantiationException, SQLException, IllegalAccessException {
        try {
            System.out.println("MySQL Connect Example.");
            Connection conn = null;
            String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
            String dbName = "evidence_db";
            String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
            String userName = "root";
            String password = "";

                Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url + dbName, userName, password);
                System.out.println("Connected to the database");
                conn.close();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(NewDBTet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Exception error:

```
Jul 16, 2012 2:59:24 PM newdbtet.NewDBTet main
SEVERE: null
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

Does this mean that I haven't installed the driver / library correctly? Sorry - not the best with Java.

Comment: What do you expect to happen?

Comment: print exceptions in catch block. There may be some exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

download the MySQL Driver for Eclipse/Java then you should get a .jar driver. then right click on your class and go to build path. finally add the external library to your project, that should solve your problem.

Comment: I've placed the library into the class (via netbeans) by going to tools> libraries> add JAR. If I right click the class, there is no option to "build path"

Answer (score 0):

Add the JDBC driver .jar into the class path with a -cp command, i.e. - `java -cp MysqlDriver.jar; MyProgram` or add the .jar into the build path in your IDE.